# 8 bit code in 7 segment display without splitting into four bit

Tags: 7segmentdisplay

How to connect two 7 segments display to display 0 to 99 number by sending 8 bit code ( without splitting code into 4 code ) using 7447 ic?

Comment: By reading the 7447's datasheet, probably. Please do your research, come up with an approach, and then ask a precise question. Google might really be your friend here; you're certainly not the first one to use 7-segment displays.

Comment: Does "without splitting code into 4 code" mean that you don't want to use BCD coding on your 8-bit lines?

Comment: Hard to believe I cant find a chip that takes 8 bits in and drives multiplexes three 7-segment displays....

Comment: Does not answer your question by MAXIM makes a nice serial interface display driver https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/datasheet/index.mvp/id/1339

Comment: @Trevor There are a couple of them at least (Maxim and a Chinese one), but they don't do binary->BCD and the 8 bits x n shifted in will be a map of the segments or something like that.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany yup, just seems like such a simple thing to do that would have been popular decades ago.

Answer (score 1):

The antediluvian 7447 works with 4 bits of BCD input. If you want to take a binary 7 bit number and display it on two decimal displays for values from 0 to 99 (0x00 to 0x63) you will have to convert it to BCD first.

There are a variety of ways to do that such as a simple lookup table (for example a ROM with 8-bit wide output and at least 7 address line). There is also the add-3 algorithm described [here](http://people.ee.duke.edu/~dwyer/courses/ece52/Binary_to_BCD_Converter.pdf) in Verilog HDL. The bottom line is that you cannot do what you are asking, you must convert binary to BCD first.

Comment: An alternative would be to use two 128x8 ROMs to drive separate 7-segment displays directly, or one 256x8 ROM to drive a multiplexed 2-digit display.  No need to convert binary to BCD--just have 128 different two-digit patterns for all possible values, an approach which would allow the system to display 28 non-numeric status codes along with numbers 00-99.

Comment: Yes, or you could even use a single 16 bit wide ROM to drive both displays directly and a bit of creative use of the two spare bits could give you the 1 or 2 needed for a third digit. But the challenge is finding ROMs that can source or sink more than a mA or two at their outputs.

Answer (score 0):

These days you need to move away from the antiquated chips from the last 30 years and move up to using a low cost MCU. In 99.5% of applications there is more to the need to just display a 00 to 99 number than just the display aspect. The 8-bit value that would drive the display content has to come from some place and most likely requires manipulation, computation, storage and a plethora of other possible things.

The MCU may be able to directly drive low current LEDs in your 7-segment displays (or can be simply buffered is needed). But to make things even better it is easy to save connections to the MCU by driving the segments of both displays at the same time and using a digit select to drive the display in a multiplex manner.

Software in the MCU does all the work and oh my what flexibility there can be!!

When it comes to actually answering your question of how to convert the 8-bit value to what is required to drive the two seven segment displays you can use a simple software look up table to translate the 8-bit value to what it takes to excite the displays connected to the MCU pins.

Answer (score 0):

Use an EPROM to convert the 8 bits to two BCD digits.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3VgXz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Since you're using 7447s, you should have no quibble with getting something like a 2716 or 2732, and a cheap programmer on eBay. Granted, you will grossly underutilize the PROM (256 locations out of 32k for a 2732), but it's getting really hard to find anything smaller.